# Apache HttpClient multiple GET requests

Tags: android, apache, get, httpclient

I'm working on simple Android app which downloads some data from web and saves that into SQLite database.

The problem is that there is a large amount of files which are needed to be saved.
I'm using Apache's `DefaultHttpClient`, and yet I do not understand how to make many GET requests.

Now the official Apache docs state that, there should be one HttpClient to make multiple connections. I have found few answers here on how to make single HttpClient per application (using Singleton classes, etc), but after that, do I need to write like, hundreds of GET requests just to download those files?.

Now, recently I have found that all the information I need is actually contained in a single XML file.

So i'm thinking about downloading that file, use parser to find what I need, and pass that information to HttpClient.

But how could I achieve something like that?

I have found many great information on official Apache docs, here, on many blogs, but none of them seems to provide, clear and simple example on how to make more that one GET request.

Or the answer is simple as that, just to write as many GET requests as I need? (But in that case, I would need hundreds if not thousands of GET requests).

OK, I know that this question may seem ridiculous, but i'm almost completely new to JAVA and Android development. Had some minor coding experience, but this is my first time i get into "serious" programming, so any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than handling the GET requests yourself (especially for large amounts of data), you are better served by the [`DownloadManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) class.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can't believe I missed something like that.